# Error in pinv(t(mx) %*% mx) : could not find function "pinv"

Tags: r

I used an R program to analyzing my thesis. And my thesis is about multivariate spline regression. When I put the syntax I got this error and I don't know how to fix it.

Could you help me?

```
Error in pinv(t(mx) %*% mx) : could not find function "pinv"
```

Comment: First [hit](https://github.com/cran/lintools/blob/master/R/pinv.R) on google search

Comment: To add to @AdamQuek's fine answer see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391548/r-ginv-and-matlab-pinv-produce-different-results) for an interesting discussion about `pinv` and `ginv`